# How do you edit a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can't seem to find the syntax for editing an already-created stored procedure in MySQL.

Comment: [here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.com/2015/01/introduction-to-stored-procedure.html) is a great tutorial on stored procedure in mysql.

Comment: @RNKushwaha if you are the downvoter, I'll mention that it is mildly annoying to get downvotes for questions that were asked nearly five years ago and were considered on topic for three years. I'm totally fine with this question being deleted, but I'm having a hard time understand who benefits from a downvote in such a case.

Comment: It was all happened by mistake. I was trying to upvote. Now it says your vote is locked. If you edit this question, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change certain attributes using the [ALTER PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-procedure.html) syntax

To change the procedure body you will have to drop and recreate the entire procedure, in this case [SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-procedure.html) may be useful

Comment: Seems like the only way. But I don't get it. When you select "Alter Procedure" (should be "Routine") in Workbench, you get a `Create` statement that works fine.

Comment: Workbench's alter routine is a workbench specific abstraction. The actual raw SQL is a ALTER PROCEDURE. If you change a procedure in workbench it will still drop and recreate.

Answer (score 19):

Mysql do not allow to alter stored procedure but SP can be drop and recreate SP options are available in Mysql like below query

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS foo;
    delimiter //
    create PROCEDURE foo (args)
    begin
      bla bla
    end//
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why in general alter is necessary?