# How to Alter a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to **Alter a stored procedure** in *Mysql*.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_Country_UPDATE; 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Country_UPDATE 
  ( IN p_CountryId int, 
    IN p_CountryName nvarchar(25), 
    IN p_CountryDescription nvarchar(25), 
    IN p_IsActive bit, 
    IN p_IsDeleted bit ) 
  UPDATE 
    Country 
  SET 
    CountryName = p_CountryName , 
    CountryDescription=p_CountryDescription, 
    IsActive= p_IsActive, 
    IsDeleted=p_IsDeleted 
  WHERE 
    CountryId = p_CountryId ;
```

How to alter this Stored Procedure?

Comment: Depends, what's your stored procedure and what have you tried?

Comment: I need the syntax to alter the stored procedure in Mysql.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-procedure.html there you go

Comment: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_Country_UPDATE`; 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Country_UPDATE
     (
        IN  p_CountryId int, 
        IN  p_CountryName nvarchar(25),
        IN  p_CountryDescription nvarchar(25),
        IN  p_IsActive bit,
        IN  p_IsDeleted bit   
     )
    UPDATE Country
    SET    
            CountryName  =  p_CountryName ,
   CountryDescription=p_CountryDescription,
         IsActive= p_IsActive,
            IsDeleted=p_IsDeleted
    WHERE  CountryId = p_CountryId ;

Comment: duplicate of [How do you edit a stored procedure in MySQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559997/how-do-you-edit-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Comment: how to alter this stored procedure...,

Comment: i want general syntax to alter stored procedure in Mysql

Comment: [here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.com/2015/01/introduction-to-stored-procedure.html) is a great tutorial on stored procedure in mysql.

Answer (score 24):

If you mean you want to edit the Procedure, then you can't according to the MySQL docs:

> This statement can be used to change the characteristics of a stored procedure. More than one change may be specified in an ALTER PROCEDURE statement. **However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored procedure using this statement; to make such changes, you must drop and re-create the procedure using DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE.**

The `Alter` syntax lets you change the "characteristics" but not the actual procedure itself

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-procedure.html

Here's an example of creating, Altering (the comment) then dropping and recreating:

```
DROP PROCEDURE myFunc;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myFunc ()
COMMENT 'test'
BEGIN
SELECT 5;
END //

DELIMITER ;

ALTER PROCEDURE myFunc
COMMENT 'new comment';

CALL myFunc();

DROP PROCEDURE myFunc;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myFunc ()
COMMENT 'last time'
BEGIN
SELECT 6;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL myFunc();
```

The above `CALL myFunc()` statments would return 5 and then 6.

Viewing the stored procedure would show a comment of "test", "new comment" or "last time" depending on when you viewed the Procedure body (I'm not sure how to view the comments via the CLI but I can see them in the *functions* tab in Navicat)

Comment: So we cannot modify the body, add/remove input parameter using alter. So for this we need to drop the existing stored procedure and again create it.

Comment: Not according to the docs no - unless anything has changed since I answered this in March

Comment: This is so much harder than Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc_name [characteristic ...]

characteristic:
    COMMENT 'string'
  | LANGUAGE SQL
  | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
  | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
```

Answer (score -8):

This is how you Create

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
BEGIN
SELECT *  FROM products;
END //
```

This is how you Alter

```
Alter PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
BEGIN
SELECT *  FROM products;
END //
```

Comment: It is not the right way to Alter a procedure w.r.t mysql