# Why my sql query not runing as I have set the right DELIMITER

Tags: mysql, delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$
ALTER PROCEDURE GetUContent（IN CurPage INT,IN PageRows INT）
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @rownum INT DEFAULT 0; 
    SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum+1 as T_ROWID,
            tcl.T_ID AS T_CID ,
            tcl.T_CONTENTS , 
            tcl.T_TYPE ,
            tcl.T_STATUS , 
            tcl.T_GOAL , 
            tcl.T_IMGURL AS T_CIMGURL , 
            tcl.T_CREATETIME ,
            tul.T_ID AS T_UID , 
            tul.T_NAME , 
            tul.T_IMGURL AS T_UIMGURL ,
            IFNULL(trl.T_RCOUNT, 0) AS T_RCOUNT 
            FROM  T_CONTENT  tcl LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT   T_CID , COUNT(T_ID) AS T_RCOUNT 
              FROM    T_REPLAY  WHERE   T_STATUS = 1  GROUP BY T_CID
            ) trl ON tcl.T_ID = trl.T_CID
             INNER JOIN  T_USERINFO tul ON tcl.T_UID = tul.T_ID
            WHERE     tcl.T_STATUS = 1
     ORDER BY tcl.T_CREATETIME LIMIT PageRows*CurPage,PageRows;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- Error Info:
  ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2 in file: '/root/git/Thinking/src/main/resources/dataScript.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CurPage INT,IN PageRows INT）
  BEGIN 
  DECLARE @rownum INT DEFAULT 0; 
  SELECT  ' at line 1

Must Infomation：

1. I use the default mysql client
2. Runing Command： . /root/git/Thinking/src/main/resources/dataScript.sql
3. The content of dataScipt.sql is the upper coding.

Comment: Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559997/how-do-you-edit-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql) can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
DECLARE rownum INT DEFAULT 0; 
SELECT  rownum=rownum+1 as T_ROWID,
...
```

because `@...` variables are session variables that cannot be used with `DECLARE`.

**EDIT**

And `ALTER PROCEDURE` [does not support changing the method body](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-procedure/) in MariaDB:

> However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored
>   procedure using this statement; to make such changes, you must drop
>   and re-create the procedure using DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE.

Comment: Think you answer my question.but the question is still when i use your way to runing my sql.

Comment: @user3073477: See my edit. `ALTER PROCEDURE` cannot be used for changing the method body.